# Laravel - custom timestamp column names

Tags: laravel, timestamp, eloquent

I am migrating a site from codeigniter to Laravel.

For a legacy table `reports`, some existing columns `created_at` and `updated_at` are named `date_created` and `date_modified` respectively.

I wish to tell my eloquent `Report` model about these custom timestamp column names.

The documentation only provide reference to turning timestamps off or providing custom timestamp formats.

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#timestamps

Comment: I was looking for it recently but have not found anything. They are tied quite deeply to the system, many methods use them as they are. What about just renaming the fields (and eventually making some custom accessor method to them, if necessary)?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In model your can define constants like this to change the column names

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {
    const CREATED_AT = 'date_created';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'date_modified';
}
```

or use you can use something like this [Managing Timestamps](https://gist.github.com/arunbsar/c63660b76f3cd5794c916ce703a0a549)

Comment: My two cents: Also make sure not to add `$timestamps = false;` or comment that `//public $timestamps = false;`. Moreover, `protected $casts = ['date_created','date_modified']`. Reference: [The docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#timestamps)