# Change column names used to save timestamp

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When storing or editing data in a table by laravel it creates a timestamp that uses the fields `created_at` and `updated_at`.

But I have to store the data in a table shared with another system, and it uses another nomenclature to store this data.

Without being the solution to set the `timestamp = false` and at the time of storing myself add the timestamp there.

In the model itself do I have to set the `cr‍‍‍‍‍‍‍eated_a‌‌‌‌‌‌t` and `updated_at` data to be saved in other columns?‍‍‍‍‍‌‌‌‌‌

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010435/laravel-custom-timestamp-column-names

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Eloquent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent) says, you can override consts on your models

```
const CREATED_AT = 'created_at_column_name';
const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at_column_name';
```