# Get timestamps column value of a random model without knowing the column name in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to get the timestamps column value like 'date_created' & 'date_modified' of a model in Laravel without knowing the name of the timestamp column? Here is the code where I want to use this function.

```
function Timestamp($model, $id)
{
    $row = $model::find($id);
    $created = isset($row->created) ? $row->created : (isset($row->created_at) ? $row->created_at
        : (isset($row->created_on) ? $row->created_on : (isset($row->date_created) ? $row->date_created : '')));
    $updated = isset($row->updated) ? $row->updated : (isset($row->updated_at) ? $row->updated_at
        : (isset($row->updated_on) ? $row->updated_on : (isset($row->date_modified) ? $row->date_modified : '')));
    
    return 'The record was created on ' . $created . ' and updated on ' . $updated;
}
```

The above code is very long, and it requires additional code to be added if the timestamp column name of a new model is different. So I want to know if there is any method to extract the timestamp column value in Laravel without knowing the column name of the timestamp if we have the model and their record ID. The reason to ask this question there are lots of places where I  using using the timestamps and I do not want to break my code. Sure I could just modify my model timestamp name to a similar name or rename the column in the database but that would simply break lots of code in many pages just for this function where I am using different column names .

Comment: Have you studied the Laravel model specification and documentation? What did you find out so far?

Comment: Okay maybe the question was too abstract again. While you searched for your question, did you stumble already over this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25010435/367456 ?

Comment: You can shorten that code to this: function Timestamp($model, $id)
{
    $row = $model::find($id);
    $created = $row->created ?? ($row->created_at ?? ($row->created_on ?? ($row->date_created ?? '')));
    $updated = $row->updated ?? ($row->updated_at ?? ($row->updated_on ?? ($row->date_modified ?? '')));
    
    return 'The record was created on ' . $created . ' and updated on ' . $updated;
}

Comment: I studied the documentation and also looked inside the vendor folder for possible code but could not find any exact solution. however, I found code to get the value of the primary key column, password column or email column so was thinking if there is a similar code for the timestamp as well.

Comment: If a model uses timestamps or not, check the `public bool $timestamps` property of it. A models class constant named `CREATED_AT` contains the name of that columns and the `UPDATED__AT` constant contains the name of that timestamp column - compare with the timestamp configuration of a model: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#timestamps - see also my answer where I outlined it. Perhaps you are always reading it but not seeing how this relates to your `$model` in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after going through every documentation and code of laravel I came to the conclusion that there is no such method to directly get the timestamp column of a model like the method to get the primary key of the model directly. However I found some method which can be combined to get the value. The two methods are

> **"__get"** (double underscore) & **getCreatedAtColumn()/getUpdatedAtColumn()**

This is how I implemented the method fr my function.

```
function Timestamp($model, $id)
    {
        $row = $model::find($id);
        $created = $row->__get($row->getCreatedAtColumn());
        $updated = $row->__get($row->getUpdatedAtColumn());
        
        return 'The record was created on ' . $created . ' and updated on ' . $updated;
    }
```

here the **getCreatedAtColumn()/getUpdatedAtColumn()** returns the name of the created and updated column respectively while the **__get** method returns the value of the column name that it receives.
Good thing about this method is that we dont have to worry if there is no timestamp column. This approach will automatically return null if timestamps is set to null or the model does not have any timestamp.

Thank you everyone for your fruitful suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> So I want to know if there is any method to extract the timestamp column value in Laravel without knowing the column name of the timestamp if we have the model and their record ID

No, not a method.

But you can read from the model - at least the part that is publicly accessible - the [timestamp configuration(s)](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#timestamps) and I think it suffices:

1. verify the `$model` is using timestamps at all
2. use the `$model` column names for both `CREATED_AT` and `UPDATED_AT` instead of the hard-encoded values you have so far (e.g. change the literal `$row` propery to the class constant).